# Aliasing of a Signal

Tags: aliasing

I am really confused about this exam question regarding Aliasing.

I have a signal of 2Hz, which I needed to draw a square wave of, over a period of 8 seconds. It Then asks,

"Starting from the square wave you plotted above, plot the resulting wave if it is sampled at a rate of 0.5Hz. What is the phenomenon occurring here."

My Question is, what is the Aliased frequency?

Comment: What are the sample values that you get when you sample at 0.5 Hz?

Comment: That's where im confused..... For a 2Hz freq at least a 4Hz SR should be ideal. But now he told us that SR = 0.5Hz, so I'm wondering what the aliased frequency would be.

Comment: Just draw the signal and take samples at 0.5 Hz and see what the corresponding values are, it's that simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

If you draw the signal and you take samples at a rate of $0.5\,\text{Hz}$, what are the sampled values that you get? Are they all different? If not, what is the frequency of a constant signal?

Comment: So, when you say I should take a sample every 0.5Hz, does that mean I should take a sample every 2 seconds (using t = 1/f)? Wouldnt that give a value of 0hz?

Comment: @melki0795: That's right.